# Openssl signing to generate JWT token

Tags: c, openssl, jwt, rsa, digital-signature

I have to generate JWT token and so i found some online resource on using OpenSSL dll (libcrypto-1_1.dll) for the same.

This method is used to get the rsa key

```
void *getRSAKey(const char *file1, int type, const char *password)
{
    void * file = NULL;
    void *rsa;
    
    file = (void*)BIO_new_file(file1, "r");

    if (file == NULL) return 0;

    if (type == 0) {
        rsa=(void*)d2i_RSAPrivateKey_bio(file, NULL);
    } else if (type == 1) {
        if(password)
            rsa=(void*)PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(file, NULL, NULL, (void*)password);
        else
            rsa=(void*)PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    
    if (rsa == NULL){
        lr_message("ras NULL ");
    }

    BIO_free(file);
    return(rsa);
}
```

First I have generated the header and payload and done base24 encoding on them. I am them concatenating these with a seperator "." and saving in input

```
input = (unsigned char*)calloc(strlen(base24encodedHeader) + strlen(base24encodedPayload) + 1,sizeof(unsigned char));
    strcpy((char*)input,base24encodedHeader);
    strcat(input, ".");
    strcat((char*)input,base24encodedPayload);
```

Then this input is being passed to RSA_sign to get the sign

```
private_key = (void*)getRSAKey(private_key_file, X509_FILETYPE_PEM, "abc");
sign = (unsigned char*)calloc(RSA_size(private_key), sizeof(unsigned char));    
RSA_sign(NID_sha256,input, strlen((char*)input), sign, &sign_len, private_key);

printf("private_key = %d",RSA_size(private_key));
printf("signed len = %d\n", sign_len);
printf("signed string = %s\n", sign);
```

finally i am concatenating input with sign

```
jwt= (char *)calloc(strlen(input) + strlen(sign) + 2,sizeof(unsigned char));
strcpy(jwt,input);
strcat(jwt,".");
strcat(jwt,sign);
printf("%s",jwt);
```

however the in the returned jwt string the "sign" is empty. And RSA_Sign is throwing error digest too big

```
private_key = 512 
input size = 761
Signed len = 5
signed string = 
signed error = error:04075070:rsa routines:RSA_sign:digest too big for rsa key
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of input string (base64) was 761 bytes, RSA signing for
SHA256 it should be 256 bits = 32 bytes, so tahts why it was throwing the error "too big"

So i needed basically to first generate a SHA256 hash of the input string before passing it to RSA_sign.